# Grouping different Columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a csv file which contains ID, Time and its distance like screenshot below. 
The file contains the distance travelled of some interval of time. Is there any way in python which I can group all 'Time' column in one and all 'Distance' column in one column for that particular ID. My target is to plot time vs distance of that particular ID at the end.

Or is there any function in python which I can plot without grouping Time and Distance Column Values.

I am open to any suggestions :)

[image]

Comment: there are same columns names?

Comment: Every hour new values for `Time` & `Distance` are added to the right, isn't it? And you want to plot only the most right `Time` vs `Distance`, right?

Comment: @jezrael, Yes these are same column names. For every time, the distance is increased and it goes on.....So i want to group all Times column into one Time Column and all Distance Column into one Distance column

Comment: @Kopytok, As for every times, the distance is added to the right. But i want to plot all the distance vs time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe after `read_excel` columns names are changed, so is possible split them by `.` for `MultiIndex` and for reshape use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (df)
   ID  Time(hr)  Distance Km  Time(hr).1  Distance Km.1  Time(hr).2  \
0   1         1            5           2             10           3   
1   2         2            0           2             10           3   

   Distance Km.2  
0             12  
1             15  

d = {'Time(hr)':'Time(hr).0','Distance Km':'Distance Km.0'}
df = df.set_index('ID').rename(columns=d)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
   ID  Distance Km  Time(hr)
0   1            5         1
1   1           10         2
2   1           12         3
3   2            0         1
4   2           11         2
5   2           15         3
```

Last for pivoting is possible use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.pivot(index='Time(hr)', columns='ID', values='Distance Km').plot()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: @user3280146 - Glad can help!